# Check if X509 Certificate matches a CertificateRequest (CSR)

Tags: go, x509, csr

How can I check if a x509 certificate matches a CSR (if the certificate was generated based on a specific CSR) in Go? Do I need to generate a new certificate from the CSR and compare them?

Comment: A certificate does not get created directly from a CSR. A CSR only contains the public key and some information which the one requesting the certificate wants to have included in the certificate. The CA only takes selected information from the CSR for the created certificate and adds some more information. There is not even a CSR needed in the first place to generate a certificate. Thus all you could check if some specific information match, like the subject and the public key.

Comment: Yes I am aware that a CA just takes the CSR's content in order to create the certificate and there is no real link between a CSR and Certificate. I just thought that could exist a function/library to check if a certificate was generated based on the content of a CSR. 
"Thus all you could check if some specific information match, like the subject and the public key": yes that will work. 
Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your signing request is in the DER format there's a couple of functions in the standard library you can use; first to parse the CSR (https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParseCertificateRequest) and then the certificate (https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParseCertificate). Once parsed you can compare the public key values.

Standard but important security note:

Please note that this DOES NOT validate the certificate in anyway. It may or may not be safe to use, and could have been substituted or altered.